Depricated - Calling where_not_equal is deprecated and will be removed
Is there someone that know how to fix this error?
I don't know what to do?
I belive it is Add-on Contact Form 7 - Mailpoet 3 plugin that is the problem.
Calling where_not_equal is deprecated and will be removed. Use \MailPoet\Newsletter\Segment\SegmentsRepository and \MailPoet\Entities\SegmentEntity instead.
Calling where_not_equal is deprecated and will be removed. Use Doctrine instead.
MailPoet\Models\Segment::deprecationError()
wp-content/plugins/mailpoet/lib/Models/Segment.php:272
MailPoet\Models\Segment::__callStatic()
wp-content/plugins/add-on-contact-form-7-mailpoet/includes/class-mailpoet-cf7-integration.php:235
MailPoet_CF7_Integration->mailpoet_segments_data()
wp-content/plugins/add-on-contact-form-7-mailpoet/includes/class-mailpoet-cf7-integration.php:123
MailPoet_CF7_Integration->mailpoet_signup_form_tag()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/form-tags-manager.php:551
WPCF7_FormTagsManager->scan_callback()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/form-tags-manager.php:460
WPCF7_FormTagsManager->replace_callback()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/form-tags-manager.php:460
preg_replace_callback()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/form-tags-manager.php:356
WPCF7_FormTagsManager->scan()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/form-tags-manager.php:328
WPCF7_FormTagsManager->replace_all()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php:881
WPCF7_ContactForm->replace_all_form_tags()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php:947
WPCF7_ContactForm->form_elements()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php:647
WPCF7_ContactForm->form_html()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form-functions.php:269
{closure}()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form-functions.php:269
wpcf7_switch_locale()
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form-functions.php:273
wpcf7_contact_form_tag_func()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:433
do_shortcode_tag()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:433
preg_replace_callback()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:273
do_shortcode()
wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/shortcodes/text_box.php:100
flatsome_text_box()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:433
do_shortcode_tag()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:433
preg_replace_callback()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:273
do_shortcode()
wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/shortcodes/ux_banner.php:177
flatsome_ux_banner()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:433
do_shortcode_tag()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:433
preg_replace_callback()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:273
do_shortcode()
wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/shortcodes/lightbox.php:23
ux_lightbox()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:433
do_shortcode_tag()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:433
preg_replace_callback()
wp-includes/shortcodes.php:273
do_shortcode()
wp-content/themes/flatsome/template-parts/header/partials/element-newsletter.php:49
load_template('wp-content/themes/flatsome/template-parts/header/partials/element-newsletter.php')
wp-includes/template.php:745
locate_template()
wp-includes/general-template.php:206
get_template_part('template-parts/header/partials/element-newsletter','nav_position_text')
wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/structure/structure-header.php:101
flatsome_header_elements()
wp-content/themes/flatsome/template-parts/header/header-bottom.php:17
load_template('wp-content/themes/flatsome/template-parts/header/header-bottom.php')
wp-includes/template.php:745
locate_template()
wp-includes/general-template.php:206
get_template_part('template-parts/header/header','bottom')
wp-content/themes/flatsome/template-parts/header/header-wrapper.php:16
load_template('wp-content/themes/flatsome/template-parts/header/header-wrapper.php')
wp-includes/template.php:745
locate_template()
wp-includes/general-template.php:206
get_template_part('template-parts/header/header','wrapper')
wp-content/themes/flatsome/header.php:33
load_template('wp-content/themes/flatsome/header.php')
wp-includes/template.php:745
locate_template()
wp-includes/general-template.php:48
get_header('shop')
wp-content/themes/flatsome/woocommerce/archive-product.php:21```

Hope someone know how to help me with this.

